# Apache2, Django. Import Error

Tags: django, python-3.x, deployment, debian, apache2

I have some problem with deployment Django app on Apache2 web server. I had so error:

> ImportError: No module named 'myproject.settings'

But I didn't know why. Could you help me?

My config file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    Alias /static /var/www/myproject/myproject/static
    <Directory /var/www/myproject/myproject/static>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/myproject/myproject/myproject>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    WSGIDaemonProcess myproject python-path=/var/www/myproject python-home=/var/www/agora/ENV
    WSGIProcessGroup myproject
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/myproject/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py

</VirtualHost>
```

And wsgi.py:

```
import os
import sys

path = '/var/www/myproject' 
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'myproject.settings'

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Structure of project:

```
project
|--ENV
|--project
|----project
|------wsgi.py
|------settings.py
```

Comment: Where is `settings.py`? Do you really have `WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/myproject/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py`? Using fake names always makes debugging stuff like this more difficult.

Comment: Yes, here try path to **wsgi.py** and **settings.py** - **/var/www/agora/agora/agora**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your settings file is in `/var/www/agora/agora/agora/settings.py`, so you need `/var/www/agora/agora` to be on the python path.

Currently, it looks like you have `python-path=/var/www/agora` on the python path instead.

If you set the python path correctly in the Apache config, then you shouldn't need to change `sys.path` in the `wsgi.py` file.

Comment: Thank, it helped me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this:

```
WSGIPythonPath /var/www/myproject/myproject
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I tried it, but this didn't help me